# Exclude uploaded files from appearing in the excerpt()

Tags: links, formatting, excerpt

In a post I have some text and some media attachments and when I use the_excerpt(), it strips all the anchor tags from the attachments and shows just their file names and its causing me problems as some of the filenames are really long. Is there a way of excluding media attachment content from the_excerpt()?

If not, is there a way to show the anchor tags when using the_excerpt() that wont leave unclosed tags and what not?

Answer (score 2):

If you manually provide an excerpt for the post WordPress will use the one you provided instead of automatically generating one. Any HTML links you include in your manual excerpt will still be displayed correctly. Or you can leave the links out and just include the text you want.

To preserve HTML links in the automatically generated excerpt you could try this tutorial: [How To preserve HTML Tags in WordPress Excerpt Without a Plugin](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-preserve-html-tags-in-wordpress-excerpt-without-a-plugin/)

Comment: Im using the_excerpt in my search template, so i would have to manually enter one for each post (theres around 500+), so I cant do that. I tried that function (as well as every other I could find on the net) but if the last word shown is a word before a link, it causes unclosed html elements :(

Comment: That is the difficulty with filtering the content. It's far easier to remove all the HTML then to look for unclosed HTML elements and close them. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Yeah, i see what you mean! I'll go a css route and work with the text overflow instead. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of excluding media attachment content from the_excerpt()?

Yes. There are many ways. Here are a few:

- Use a [manual excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt).
- Write more text before the first link to an image in the post.
- Shorten the [length of the excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Control_Excerpt_Length_using_Filters).
- Use the [`'get_the_excerpt'` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt) to change content of the excerpt.